# flutter ios build fail - do i need to enroll apple developer?

Tags: ios, flutter

I am starter of flutter.
I finished building my first app and I want to export ipa app to give my friends.
I don't want to release to apple app store, I just want to use myself(and my friends).

So, once I input `flutter build ios` (also i tried `flutter build ios --debug` ) ,

```
Running "flutter pub get" in mighty_v2...                           4.0s
Building com.example.mightyV2 for device (ios-release)...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: 66H5V644W9
Running pod install...                                           2,370ms
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                            5.3s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    error: No profiles for 'com.example.mightyV2' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.example.mightyV2'. Automatic
    signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild. (in target 'Runner' from project
    'Runner')
```

above error was founded.

I already know what is wrong. My problem is, do not enrolled apple developer, and do not enrolled my app profiles init.

So question is, do I have to enroll and give 100$? I just use this app myself although the app is debug mode. I just want light ipa file. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

It can be two things. First you need to create a iOS App Development provisioning profile,to create that click on Xcode at top of the screen beside apple logo then > preferences > accounts here you will find you apple id and below that you will see download manual profiles and manage certificate options. Create a profile here and clean the build folder then build again.

Second, if you have the provisioning profile and still won't be able to create the .ipa file from Product > Archive then you definitely need a developer account.

Comment: I already enroll preferences > accounts and write down my apple id. 
So, second is the answer. There are no way to export ipa app..

Comment: Can you explain me how you trying to build the .ipa file ?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to have a developer account if you are not publishing. However, you will have to open your app in Xcode and go to the *Signing & Capabilities* tab under *Runner* to set a *Team* in order to build. This can be any Apple ID.

Using this method, you will not be able to just send the .ipa to your friends and them easily install it. You will need to push to their phones via Xcode.

I encourage you to checkout Firebase App Distribution as a much easier, free alternative to distribute your app to your friends if you do not want to publish yet.

Comment: so there are not any way to export ipa file like android apk file....

Comment: No. Sideloading on iOS requires Xcode or jailbroken devices. iOS's security measures regarding installing apps from unknown sources are much stricter than Android's.